# Enabling MSSQL Connection with PHP 5.6 for IIS 8.5 webserver

Tags: php, iis, database-connection, php-5.6

I'm facing a problem with enabling a mssql connection to the DB with PHP 5.6 on my IIS 8.5 webserver.

Starting point:
I'm migrating our "`networkshareaccess-order-phptool`" (Orders for acces on a networkshare for internal employees) from PHP 5.2/IIS 6.0/Windows Server 2003 to PHP 5.6/IIS 8.5/Windows Server 2012 R2. So far so good. I could finish the whole migration except the establishing of the connection to the MS SQL database.

I get the following fatal error:

> Call to undefined function **mssql_connect()** in "Path" on line **144**

The php code and the user/userpermissions in MS SQL are right. I added the `php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll` in the PHP ext folder, enabled it in the extension section in the php.ini file and added the FastCGI to the Handler Mappings.

I read several threads about this topic but I couldn't solve the issue. When I check the phpinfo on the new server there's no mssql section.

Does someone know what the problem could be in this case?

BR

Comment: Do you have the ODBC driver 11 for SQL Server installed?

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Comment: Yes I do, the error still occures respectively the mssql isn't available in phpinfo